# Colored Window Theme in Pharo?

Tags: settings, smalltalk, pharo

How do I switch to the colored window theme in Pharo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure which theme you mean but have you tried

world menu -> System -> Settings -> Appearance -> Morphic -> User interface theme?

The select box will let you choose the window color theme.

Comment: Thank you—works for most windows, but shouldn’t the browser window be green? I get them in gray, how can I fix this?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure which theme you mean. Is it that flat one with the green OB browser windows and grey Monticello windows from Squeak?

Comment: Yes, the theme with the colored windows as in Squeak. I used your approach to set the theme to Squeak but the system browser windows are still grey instead of green (for most other windows the colors seem to work).

Comment: Apparently, there are quite some `patchworkUIThemeColor` methods missing on the class side. For example in OBSystemBrowser etcetera. Without these methods the windows are just gray. Maybe you can update your answer to include that!

Answer (score 2):

Or...by code... execute:
                      XXXTheme beCurrent.

Comment: There seems to be no `XXXTheme` in my image.

Comment: Search for "Theme" in Finder and you will see which themes you actually have, and do e.g: BlueUITheme beCurrent

Answer (score 1):

Best neat way to do this is to install the TWM (Tiled Windows Manager) and use its theme.

That the closest you'll get to a squeak colorful windows meets pharo theme.

You can get the theme without activating TWM in the prefs (although TWM is cool).

Answer (score 0):

It is a setting and as such you can select it from the settings tool

Right click on the Pharo desk to open the world menu 
-> System -> Settings -> Appearance -> User interface theme

Themes are classes within the system, usually implemented as
subclasses of class UITheme.
Evaluate

UITheme browseHierarchy

to open a browser to view them all and see the source code or inspect

UITheme allSubclasses

which gives a collection of the following classes

UIThemeStandardSqueak 
  UIThemeVistary 
  UIThemeWatery 
  UIThemeW2K 
  BlueUITheme 
  UIThemeWatery2 
  PharoTheme 
  PharoOrangeTheme

in the Pharo 1.4 image.

If you send the message #beCurrent to one of this classes you can
activate it programmatically, so

UIThemeW2K beCurrent

will switch to Windows2000 like user interface, while

UIThemeWatery2 beCurrent

to a Mac like user interface. You can implement your own if you like
by adding an own subclass.

Comment: So "UIThemeStandardSqueak beCurrent" would give you the colored environment known from Squeak