# UI Theme Repository for Pharo?

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, color-scheme, pharo

I'm still pretty green when it comes to Pharo so apologies in advance for what might well be a pretty dumb question. I've already done a perfunctory google search and checked out this [stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569611/colored-window-theme-in-pharo) which didn't have the answer I need. I'm looking for a ready-made color theme that has a black background. Understand, I'm not just looking to change the wallpaper background color, I want the all the windows, widgets, and window contents (workspace text in particular) to be appropriately modified as well. I'm assuming someone somewhere has already done this, I just don't know where to find it (I can't be the only one who codes at 3am and doesn't like staring at the giant light-bulb that is my monitor!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to here, David :).

[pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) is still young and fast growing and there are not many themes. So Esteban Lorenzano is working on a dark theme based on InteliJ IDEA, and you can find it here: http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~estebanlm/Pharo3DarkTheme, but it will take a long time until it's done.

Comment: that's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. thanks, Uko! I'll install it once it's a bit closer to beta.

Comment: @DavidDaedalus you are welcome! Remember that this is Pharo, so you are free and welcome to submit your contributions

Comment: when I understand the language well enough to submit - I most certainly will! (still going through Pharo by Example)